# value error for simple definition to generate list of colors

Tags: python, pandas, definition, valueerror

I am making a simple definition to return a list of colors based on some intervals. Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have seen the following discussion on stackoverflow but only had failed attempts to make it work.

[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

This is my code:

```
y = 5
std = pd.Series([1,1,1,1])
values = pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8])
colors = []
def colorbybar():
    for i in values:
        if y < (values - (2*std)):
            colors[i] = 'darkblue'
        elif y < (values - std):
            colors[i] = 'blue'
        elif y < values:
            colors[i] = 'white'
        elif y < (values + std):
            colors[i] = 'red'
        elif y < (values + (2*std)):
            colors[i] = 'darkred'
    return colors

colorbybar()
```

Comment: Please do not [post your question again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/217657) if you haven’t got a meaningful answer to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727910/definition-in-python-to-return-color). Next time, edit the original question to improve it instead.

Comment: `colors` is already a global variable.  You don't need to return it.

Comment: Has any of the answers solved your problem? Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657) it (✓) or clarify your needs by [edit]ing or comments. You can also [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (▲) useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `y < (values - std)` it will return `pd.Series`

```
>>> y < (values - std)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

but here you need scalar `bool` for condition so as said in error use

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

like

```py
>>> (y < (values - std)).all()
False
>>> # or
>>> (y < (values - std)).any()
True
```

Thus your function would be

```
def colorbybar():
    for i in values:
        if (y < (values - (2*std))).all():
            colors[i] = 'darkblue'
        elif (y < (values - std)).all():
            colors[i] = 'blue'
        elif (y < values).all():
            colors[i] = 'white'
        elif (y < (values + std)).all():
            colors[i] = 'red'
        elif (y < (values + (2*std))).all():
            colors[i] = 'darkred'
    return colors
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!
The error is gone but it returns an empty list..

Comment: I don't know your logic i mean you have to use `all` or `any` as per your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven’t fully understood how Python’s [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) works. It does not introduce any index (like in many other languages) but iterates over the members (like `foreach` in many languages).

In your loop, you are trying to do arithmetic operations on `values`, i.e. the whole Series, as [Dishin demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61730078/711006). You probably wanted to operate on the *items* of `values`. You introduced the variable `i` in your `for` statement but let me choose the name `value` to express what it does:

```
for value in values:
    if y < (value - (2*std)):
    # and so on
```

The same applies to `std` which is a sequence, too. The easiest way to [iterate two sequences at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel) seems to be `zip()`:

```
for value, std_item in zip(values, std):
    if y < (value - (2*std_item)):
```

Another problem is that you are trying to use `i` as indices (keys) of newly created items of the list `colors`. This is not possible with a list. You could use a dictionary to set keys in such a way but that’s probably not what you wanted according to your description (judging from an [archived version of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61727910/3)):

> I am trying to make a definition that returns a list of colors based on whether a value is between some interval. Therefore, if y was -1 it should return the list [darkblue, darkblue, darkblue, darkblue], but if y was 11 it should return the list [darkred, darkred, darkred, darkred].

Instead of the wrong syntax `colors[i] = 'darkblue'`, you could use `colors.append('darkblue')` etc.

And by the way, what to do if an item in `values` exceeds all the limits? Shouldn’t there be a color, too?

This is the result:

```
y = 5
std = pd.Series([1,1,1,1])
values = pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8])
colors = []
def colorbybar():
    for value, std_item in zip(values, std):
        if y < (value - (2*std_item)):
            colors.append('darkblue')
        elif y < (value - std_item):
            colors.append('blue')
        elif y < value:
            colors.append('white')
        elif y < (value + std_item):
            colors.append('red')
        elif y < (value + (2*std_item)):
            colors.append('darkred')
        else:  # added myself
            colors.append('black')
    return colors

colorbybar()
```

And as [stark pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61729765/value-error-for-simple-definition-to-generate-list-of-colors/61751606#comment109227651_61729765), there are more things to improve with your function (`def`). As it’s currently written, it would only work *once* as expected, although functions are usually made to work repeatedly. When you called it again, it would reuse existing global variables, including `colors`. In your case, `y`, `std`, and `values` should be parameters and `colors` a local variable that is returned at the end. This way your function will be easily reusable.

```
def colorbybar(y, std, values):
    colors = []
    for value, std_item in zip(values, std):
        if y < (value - (2*std_item)):
            colors.append('darkblue')
        elif y < (value - std_item):
            colors.append('blue')
        elif y < value:
            colors.append('white')
        elif y < (value + std_item):
            colors.append('red')
        elif y < (value + (2*std_item)):
            colors.append('darkred')
        else:  # added myself
            colors.append('black')
    return colors

colorbybar(5, pd.Series([1,1,1,1]), pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8]))
```